# Post GWT input to a PHP page

Tags: php, xml, gwt, request

I have a GWT app with inputs (let's say Name, Address, Email). After user input all the required fields and press submit button, a PHP page will display the inputs from the GWT app. How can I connect my GWT app to php? I'm using Request Builder now. Do I still have to use XML to pass the GWT inputs to PHP? Please help. I'm just starting to learn GWT here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need RequestBuilder for something like that.
It would be sufficient if you redirect to the PHP url and append your inputs as GET parameters.
So for example in the click handler you can do something like that:

```
submitButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        String linkURL = "somePage.php?name="+name+"&address="+address+"&email="+email;
         Window.Location.assign(linkURL);
    }
});
```

and then in the PHP page you can retrieve the parameters in this way:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$address = $_GET['address'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
```

**Update**

If you want to use RequetBuilder you have to do something like that:

```
submitButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        RequestBuilder request = new RequestBuilder(POST,PHP_URL);
        JSONObject jsonValue = new JSONObject();
        jsonValue.put("name", new JSONString(name));
        jsonValue.put("address", new JSONString(address));
        jsonValue.put("email", new JSONString(email));
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.sendRequest(jsonValue.toString(),new RequestCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                     //retrieve a uniqueid or so and redirect to the PHP page which displays the infos
                } else {
                   // displayError("Couldn't retrieve 

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                 //displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
            }
         });

    }
});
```

On the server you just access the global **$_POST** variable to get the values:

```
$name = @_POST['name']
```

Comment: hello. Thank you for answering this question. Actually, I've already done this but I was thinking what if I have to pass data like passwords? This one's not safe. Can I use XML/JSON to pass this instead? I still don't know a thing about JSON but I've read that it can be used to pass GWT to PHP. I just don't know how to exactly do it :(

Comment: Passwords is another issue. However I don' think you will be much safer with RequestBuilder anyways because RequestBuilder is also "only" creating a HTTP request as if you would do it via the normal browser URL. With RequestBuilder you can use POST instead (still they can be read out). See my update for details

Comment: hi timeu. what code will i put on my server side? sorry if i don't know a thing here.. :(

Comment: see my update. RequestBuilder basically just creates a HTTP request. It's the same as if you would directly call the php page.

Comment: it doesn't work in my code. i've tried this one. actually, my `php` code is something like this: `foreach( $_POST as $key=>$value ) {
  echo "$key : $value<br />";
 }`

Comment: Hmm weird. Can you also output the $_GET variable. You can also use firebug to check if your payload is in your HTTP request

Comment: actually, i also included the global $_GET variable but still no output :(

Comment: when i print the `request.getRequestData()`, it returns `null`. then, i tried using `request.setRequestData(jsonValue.toString)`, `request.setCallback(new RequestCallback(){...})` and `request.send()`. it can now retrieve the `requestData` but still no output viewed in the `php` page :(

Comment: try to put a dummy string into setRequestData() instead of jsonValue.toString() and also check with firebug the HTTP Request. It should show up in the XHR request under the NET Tab.